# delete commit history without revert

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I created a branch, pushed several times with different commits, for testing purpose I have to deploy to server that's why I have many funny commits and push for that branch.. Now I'm done testing, how can I delete previous commit and I only need one commit to make a PR?

Comment: You really might want to update the title of the question.  Because you don't want to delete the commit history and you are not reverting.  What you want is to create a single commit that has all the changes on that branch.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of squashing everything into a single commit.  It depends upon what you want as a result.  If you want the new commit to be on the master branch then you could checkout out master, merge topic into master with --squash, and it should create a new single commit that can be pushed to server.  Or you could perform an interactive rebase and squash everything on the current topic branch and force push.

Here are examples:
https://robots.thoughtbot.com/git-interactive-rebase-squash-amend-rewriting-history

Comment: even though I've pushed several times?

Comment: Yes,  that doesn't matter so much if you have proper privileges.  I don't know the syntax off hand but on your local machine you can do an interactive rebase on your topic branch, squash everything into single commit, and then force push that to the server.  On the server it will discard all the old branch commits and replace with new branch commit.

Comment: squash left me with conflicts, isn't it easier to take my latest code and merge with a fresh develop branch?

Comment: `git rebase -i master topic` works.  It'll rewrite history for the topic branch and if you choose to squash everything there won't be any conflicts.  Did you skip commits or squash them?

Comment: squash. why I need to squash master? now I'm on my feature branch.

Comment: I never said to squash master nor does the command in my comment squash master.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure that **no one is using this branch** too or create some derived branch from it. Also, make a backup from your modifications if something goes wrong.

After that, you can count how many commits are in that situation. Per example, if you have 6 funny commits to undo but need to preserve the file changes, just:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~6
```

This command will undo the 6 local commits and show in your `git status` all changes on the files among these 6 commits.

Now just do your single commit:

```
git commit -am "Very nice and not funny commit message"
```

After that you can't just do a `git push`, because your local branch now is very different from the remote branch (with the 6 old commits).

So, you need to force the push to override the actual branch on remote branch:

```
git push -f
```

Comment: funny comment but the codes is actually needed in my previous commit, I need not the commit history or msg but the code is useful for my last commit.